# Keep android view in visible area if keyboard comes up

Tags: android

I created a simple login screen that stacks a login button, the username and password edit boxes vertically from the bottom.

When someone clicks the username/password fields, the virtual keyboard comes up and hids the editbox or button below it. I have seen this in another application that the login button always stays in the visible area.... how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a blog post for that: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 10):

In your `<activity>` element of the `AndroidManifest.xml` use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Make sure you have wrapped the content of your layout into a `ScrollView`, so that it will be easily browsable.